# org-agenda TODO list gives error "trying to switch to non-existent buffer"

Tags: org-agenda

I just started emacs with doom-emacs.  I open my org-agenda with `SPC o A` then `t` to my TODO list.

When I try to go to one of the TODO items with a `ENTER`, sometimes I'm given the following error.

```
Trying to switch to non-existent buffer
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you do `C-x C-f <filename>` for the file in question (the file that contains the TODO item that you are trying to visit) and then go back to the TODO list buffer and press ENTER, does it work?

Comment: @NickD `C-x C-f file-X` opens the file for me.  Then I go back to the TODO list, press `ENTER` on an item in `file-X`.   `Trying to switch to non-existent buffer` occurs.

Comment: Could be a doom emacs issue?  I'm also curious how emacs seems remember the variable `org-agenda-files` after I changed the variable and exited emacs.

Comment: It does not: you need to set it in your init file somehow. I have all my agenda files in a single directory `~/lib/org`, so I have this in my ~/.emacs.d/init.el: `(setq org-agenda-files (list (expand-file-name "~/lib/org/")))` but there are several other ways: do `C-h v org-agenda-files` for details.

Comment: Finally I found it! `~/.doom.d/custom.el`